# How to display array of structure pointer in user space which is copied from kernel via read call

Tags: linux-kernel

Depending on the number of processes currently running, by using for_each_process macro call and one simple counter, I have used kmalloc to allocate memory for those processes to store process pid and its parent pid in structure. And use copy_to_user to copy it into the user space segment like below,

copy_to_user(buffer, &data, sizeof(Data) * process_counter);

But the problem is I am not able to figure out how should I suppose to display it on the user space application using read system call.
Is it possible in one read call Or do i need to use while loop for it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Is it possible in one read call Or do i need to use while loop for it ?` - When using `read` call, user code should specify maximum amount of bytes to read. If the code is able to allocate buffer large enough for contain information about all processes, single `read` call is sufficient. Otherwise `read` calls should be repeated until EOF.

Comment: int bytes; while(bytes != EOF) { bytes = read(user_buffer, &struct_Variable, anymaxlength); display data } is it what you are suggesting ?

Comment: If `struct_Variable` is allocated array of `n` data structures, then you may use `sizeof(Data) * n` as `anymaxlength`. Actual number of structures filled after read should be determined by `bytes` value.

Comment: Hi Tsyvarev, i used some other approach. Thanks a lot!